# Confused about solving PDEs by defining new variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, substitution

My course's notes say that for a function $u=u(x,y)$, if we define $\alpha = x+ay$, and $\beta = x+by$, then:

$u_x = u_\alpha + u_\beta$, and $u_y = au_\alpha + bu_\beta$.

And this can help solve the PDE.

However I fail to see the reasoning for why the above holds.

I know of the chain rule's multivariable case, e.g. for $f(x(t), y(t))$, then $f_t = f_x x_t + f_y y_t$. But I can't seem to apply this to the case above?

Comment: The chain rule says that $u_x = u_\alpha \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x} + u_\beta \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$ and now it's just a matter of computing the partial derivatives. Similar expression applies for $u_y$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the chain rule formula right there and you can't apply it?

\begin{align} u_x &= u_\alpha \alpha_x + u_\beta \beta_x = u_\alpha + u_\beta \\
 u_y &= u_\alpha \alpha_y + u_\beta \beta_y = a u_\alpha + bu_\beta \end{align}

Since $\alpha_x = \beta_x = 1$, $\alpha_y = a$, $\beta_y = b$